# Save as Macro for active worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have encountered an error when i try to execute this vba. Basically i am trying to save the active worksheet with the code below.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim varResult As Variant
Dim dirPath, fileName As String


dirPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
fileName = ActiveSheet.Range("J5").Value 'ActiveSheet.Name


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
                 "Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls) (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Save As", _
                InitialFileName:=dirPath & "\" & fileName)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CBC").SaveCopyAs fileName:=varResult

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error you are encountering?

Comment: if i cancel the save as, i will receive a debug or run time error from vba and would like to close the workbook also if i canceled the save as option

Comment: Look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386511/how-to-handle-no-or-cancel-on-workbook-saveas-overwrite-confirmation). It takes into account error handling that you may not have thought of

Comment: Some thoughts. (1) If ActiveSheet.Range("J5") really holds the ActiveShet.Name, then why don't you say `fileName = ActiveSheet.Name`? (2) If the workbooks was never saved before it doesn't have any `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path`. (3) What's the value of `varResult` if the user presses Cancel? Step through your code using F8 and look at the values as they develop in the Locals window. Then add IF conditions to your code to deal with the eventualities. You still didn't say on which line your code crashes, or what's the message.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write comment (too low reputation) so as an answer.
I think that you are trying to save a worksheet, but SaveCopyAs can be used only with Workbook object.
Try this: [Macro to save only the active worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941546/macro-to-save-only-the-active-worksheet)